# Could not run pexect with cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, pexpect

Getting following errors while executing the pexpect example file at a Cygwin prompt.
Can anyone help?

```
Administrator@INDSQA2253 /cygdrive/c/Python26/Tools/pexpect-2.1/examples
$ python ssh_session.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh_session.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pexpect import *
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pexpect.py", line 83, in <module>
    Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.""")
ImportError: No module named resource
A critical module was not found. Probably this operating system does not support
 it.
Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.
```

Can Pexpect work with a Python for Windows, invoked from Cygwin?

Comment: I found some blog post that says it's possible, but I'm not sure I understand the nuance of what I currently have installed vs what this guy says. 
http://techi2teach.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-get-python-pexpect-module-on.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Python from cygwin. I mean cygwin's Python, that can be installed